# [rospack] Error: the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I installed ROS (melodic)/Gazebo using the instructions and a shell file found [here](https://dev.px4.io/master/en/setup/dev_env_linux_ubuntu.html#rosgazebo). I am new to this field, so I was going through http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/, and in [section 5.1 of the Creating a Package page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#ROS.2FTutorials.2Fcatkin.2FCreatingPackage.First-order_dependencies), there was a step that told me to run `$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`.

When I did that, I got the error from the title:

`[rospack] Error: the rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'`

I followed what it said and tried `sudo rosdep init` and I got `sudo: rosdep: command not found` and when I did  `rosdep update` I got `Command 'rosdep' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install python-rosdep2`.

Running the `install` command overwrites packages installed by the shell file, and that causes a lot more errors when trying to build the file, so I overwrote those changes by installing from the shell file again. My question is, how do I fix this error without installing python-rosdep2, because that is obviously causing problems.

I'm pretty new to this field, so I don't know if this is sufficient information, but please let me know if you can help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353570/%5Brospack%5D-error:-the-rosdep-view-is-empty:-call-%27sudo-rosdep-init%27-and-%27rosdep-update%27/) by [kadhirus99](https://answers.ros.org/users/55340/kadhirus99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-05-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hillripper21](https://answers.ros.org/users/36849/hillripper21/) on 2020-06-01**:
Same issue in ROS Noetic. And installing python-rosdep2 broke a bunch of other things

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try 'sudo apt-get install python3-rosdep'. This should fix the issue

---

Originally posted by [rohitn](https://answers.ros.org/users/56459/rohitn/) with karma: 21 on 2020-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [traemand](https://answers.ros.org/users/64161/traemand/) on 2020-11-27**:
This didn't fix the issue on ubuntu 20.04, noetic

**Comment by [traemand](https://answers.ros.org/users/64161/traemand/) on 2020-11-27**:
What seemed to fix my issue was running $ rosdep update , as suggested by Dirk Thomas in: https://answers.ros.org/question/65650/rosdep-error-view-is-empty/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using following order I solved for Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic my problem after getting:

> [rospack] Error: the rosdep view is
> empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and
> 'rosdep update'

1:

```
$ rosdep update
```

Command 'rosdep' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-rosdep2

2:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-rosdep2
```

0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 150 to remove and 301 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 89.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

3:

```
$ rosdep update
```

4:

```
$ sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

0 upgraded, 150 newly installed, 1 to remove and 301 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [mrsofta](https://answers.ros.org/users/64671/mrsofta/) with karma: 21 on 2020-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gniu_GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/65674/gniu_gt/) on 2020-12-15**:
Thank you, I had a similar issue and this fixed it

**Comment by [Guenter X. Qiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/66565/guenter-x.-qiu/) on 2020-12-26**:
Thanks a lot! I also had the same probelm. After following your steps, the problem has been solved.